# Como solucionar error , al ejecutar "npm start": npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.?

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, wordpress

[image: Screenshot Error a la ejecucion de "npm start"]

Compañeros, al momento de ejecutar el comando "npm start" en la terminal me aparece el siguiente error, el cual desconozco la causa, debido a que ya instale "wp-scripts" y me genero correctamente la carpeta de "node_modules", su gentil ayuda con alguna solucion a este inconveniente.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pizzashop_gutenberg@1.0.0 start: wp-scripts start
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pizzashop_gutenberg@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-30T16_33_39_524Z-debug.log
```

En verdad, ya desconozco que comando debería ingresar en la terminal.
Muchas Gracias.

Adjunto el codigo de Package.json, y ejectivamente ya ejecute el comando "npm install".

```
{
  "name": "pizzashop_gutenberg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Add to blocks of Gutenberg",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
    "start": "wp-scripts start"
  },
  "author": "Avellaneda",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^5.5.0",
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^13.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

==========Codigo de Error Completo=======

```
npm start

> pizzashop_gutenberg@1.0.0 start C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg
> wp-scripts start

C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

Error: Cannot find module 'toml'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js   
- C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
- C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\webpack.config.js:1:76)     
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
    at C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45       
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
    at C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8        
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Local Sites\the-pizza-shop\app\public\wp-content\plugins\pizzashop_gutenberg\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Local Sites\\the-pizza-shop\\app\\public\\wp-content\\plugins\\pizzashop_gutenberg\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Local Sites\\the-pizza-shop\\app\\public\\wp-content\\plugins\\pizzashop_gutenberg\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\utils\\convert-argv.js',
    'C:\\Users\\User\\Local Sites\\the-pizza-shop\\app\\public\\wp-content\\plugins\\pizzashop_gutenberg\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',    'C:\\Users\\User\\Local Sites\\the-pizza-shop\\app\\public\\wp-content\\plugins\\pizzashop_gutenberg\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js' 
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pizzashop_gutenberg@1.0.0 start: `wp-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pizzashop_gutenberg@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-30T17_27_23_239Z-debug.log
```

Desconozco si se debe añadir otra dependencia que requiera la aplicación web, o introducir otra comando, muy agradecido por su ayuda.

Comment: Faltan detalles para poder ayudarte, ¿qué hay en el archivo `package.json` en la sección de scripts? ¿Ya ejecutaste `npm install`?

Comment: estimado @MauricioContreras, agradezco tu ayuda,  adjunto el codigo del "package.json", y efectivamente he realizado la ejecution de dicho comando, por lo que dezconozco que otro paso me esta faltando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimados, al revisar un poco el percance obtenido anteriormente parece que solo ha necesitado la instalacion de "toml", ejecute dicho comando y al parecer a funcionado al momente de correr el comando "nmp start"

Lo he encontrado en esta web https://www.npmjs.com/package/toml
El comando para resolver el bug era: "npm install toml".

Agradezco de todas formas su gentil ayuda, comparto la esta solución, en caso de que les ocurra algo similar.